# How to read value from JSON which is string

Tags: c#, json, parsing

I've got a question. I try to get value from JSON. 
JSON have been sent from server by socket. 
In Client I've got sth like this:

```
            string data = null;
            // Receive the response from the remote device.  
            int bytesRec = sender.Receive(bytes);
            data += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, bytesRec);
            Console.WriteLine(data);
            Console.ReadLine();
```

And in console I see :

```
{"player":0, "size":3}
```

How can I get value from this String ?

Comment: `{"player":0 "size":3}` is not valid JSON, it should be `{"player":0, "size":3}`

Comment: yes, thats correct, spelling mistake

Comment: If you can afford to have external libraries, consider using [JSON.Net](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json)

Comment: Have you tried JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YourModel>(data);

Answer (score 9, accepted):

it is very simple. first download this nuget via Package Manager Console:

```
Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json -Version 11.0.2
```

then add this namespace:
    Newtonsoft.Json.Linq

```
JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(data);

int player = jObject["player"].Value<int>();
```

Answer (score 2):

You could create a class:

```
public class MyObject
{
    public int Player {get; set;}
    public int Size {get; set;}
}
```

And then deserialize the JSON string using something like JSON.NET:

```
MyClass myClassObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObject>(data);
var playerId = myClassObject.Player;
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a class for that JSON.

The easiest way to do this is to use Visual Studio: Copy the JSON text into the clipboard then select `Edit | Paste Special | Paste JSON as classes`. Rename the class as desired (for this example, call it Demo).

2. Add to your project a NuGet reference to `Newtonsoft.Json`
3. Deserialize via `Demo result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Demo>("{\"player\":0, \"size\":3}");`

Example console app:

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace Demo
{
    public class Demo
    {
        public int player { get; set; }
        public int size { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Demo result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Demo>("{\"player\":0, \"size\":3}");

            Console.WriteLine(result.player); // "0"
            Console.WriteLine(result.size);   // "3"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Add the Nuget package for JSON.net:**

In the Nuget Package Manager search for "Newtonsoft.Json".

Or use the console:

```
Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json
```

**Once installed you can use the following code for an anonymous type:**

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

var anonymousTypeDefinition = new { player = -1, size = -1 };
var player = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(data, anonymousTypeDefinition);
```

**Or you can use the following code for a strong type:**

```
public class Player
{
    int Size { get; set; }
    int Player { get; set; }
}

// in the console
var player = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Player>(data);
```